# Groupbox Timer Elapsed with Inline Parameters

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, timer

I am having trouble understanding why one of my parameters in my elapsed timer for my groupbox does not work.

My development team and I have many different applications and we wanted to have a centralized place for notifications for those apps. So I created a database which stores some basic information (Name of app, Refresh frequency etc).

So what I am currently doing is using a FlowLayoutPanel and dynamically creating Groupboxes on that for all the apps we have. If the logged on user has at least one notification for that application, I want to create a groupbox with a timer (that will refresh all the methods associated with the app). That works fine and it looks something like this: [App GroupBoxes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sGJ4b.png)

When the user clicks a label, it launches the application, and then disposed the groupbox. When that happens the timer for that groupbox starts and when it's elasped it will recreate that groupbox if the user has any notifications.

The issue I am having is in my code:

```
GroupBox gbItem = new GroupBox();
gbItem.Text = lstDistinctApps[i];
gbItem.Tag = Convert.ToInt32(_dtNotifications.Rows[j]["Frequency"]);
gbTimer.Interval = Convert.ToInt32(gbItem.Tag) * 5000;
gbTimer.Elapsed += (sender, e) => GBTimerElapsed(sender, e, gbItem.Text, Convert.ToInt32(gbItem.Tag));
gbTimer.Start();
```

And the elapsed event:

```
private void GBTimerElapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e, string appName, int frequency)
{
        //Dynamically creates a groupbox timer for that groupbox and during the elapsed event it refreshes the notifications for that app
        ReloadNotificationGroupBox(appName);
        System.Timers.Timer tmr = sender as System.Timers.Timer;
        tmr.Dispose();
}
```

When the user clicks a label inside of the GroupBox this section of code is ran:

```
 int refreshFreq = Convert.ToInt32(label.Parent.Tag);//GetAppRefreshFrequency(label.Parent.Text);
 if (refreshFreq != 0)
 {        
    label.Parent.Dispose();
    //TODO: Dispose old timer associated with the group
 }
```

I can hit the elapsed event just fine however when the GroupBox is disposed the appName comes out blank but the frequency is there. I have tried many things such as putting the appName in the gbItem.Tag field but I hit the elapsed event and it was blank again. 
The last thing I tried was writing this:

```
string appName = gbItem.Text;
gbTimer.Elapsed =+ (sender, e) => GBTimerElapsed(sender, e, appName, Convert.ToInt32(gbItem.Tag));
```

And I was able to get the appName with the frequency.
I have been scratching my head trying to figure out how the frequency was retained when the object was disposed.

Am I not disposing of the GroupBox correctly?
Or is there a better way to do what I am trying to do?

Comment: appName is the GroupBox.Text property.  You disposed it.  You need to create a class to keep track of everything.  Including that timer btw, one timer to handle multiple boxes isn't right.

Comment: @HansPassant It was disposed but the GroupBox.Tag information was retained but the GroupBox.Text was not. I was trying to figure out why. I can try to keep a class to handle it all but everything is dynamic. Apps will be added/removed quite frequently so I don't know if keeping them in a class is the best way for me to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without a good [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) it's impossible to understand your code and context completely. So I'll focus on what can be seen with some certainty…

> And I was able to get the appName with the frequency. I have been scratching my head trying to figure out how the frequency was retained when the object was disposed.

This comes down to how the two different properties, `Text` and `Tag`, are implemented. Technically, you shouldn't be accessing *either* property after the object is disposed. But only for the `Text` property is this critical. The `Tag` property is implemented as strictly a .NET feature. The rough equivalent in the native API might be something like `SetWindowLong()`, but because `Tag` has to deal with managed objects, it wouldn't make sense to use that as the underlying implementation.

But the `Text` property does correspond directly to the native API's idea of "window text", and so that property goes through the native Windows API, using `GetWindowText()` to retrieve the window's text. If the window handle for the control is invalid (e.g. you've disposed the control), then only if the text is cached in the object's `text` field will it be returned. And that only happens if the value was set when the window handle isn't currently valid (not the case in your situation).

In reality, for the most reliable and consistent code, you probably ought to be handling both properties the same. I.e. if you want to retrieve the value that was current at the time you subscribed to the timer's event, then you should assign them to local variables and use those in your anonymous method, so that those local variables are captured by the anonymous method and the values you care about are used at the appropriate time.

For example:

```
GroupBox gbItem = new GroupBox();
string text = lstDistinctApps[i];
int frequency = Convert.ToInt32(_dtNotifications.Rows[j]["Frequency"]);
gbItem.Text = text;
gbItem.Tag = frequency;
gbTimer.Interval = frequency * 5000;
gbTimer.Elapsed += (sender, e) => GBTimerElapsed(sender, e, text, frequency);
gbTimer.Start();
```

FWIW, note that, while I can't speak for the initial retrieval of the `frequency` value, once you have boxed the `int` value, you don't need to call `Convert.ToInt32()` to convert back to `int`. A simple case is sufficient. And of course, even better is if you can (as above) just preserve the value in a variable of the correct type and use it directly.

> Am I not disposing of the GroupBox correctly? Or is there a better way to do what I am trying to do?

"Better" is subjective, especially here. There's just not very much information in the question. That said, I don't see anything particularly troubling about the code you shared, other than minor details such as the extra calls to `Convert.Int32()` that weren't needed.

It's possible you would find the code works better if you don't dispose the control until you're also sure you're done with the timer. One way to accomplish that might be to go ahead and stop the timer before you dispose the object. But you'd want to switch to using `System.Windows.Forms.Timer`, so that you can ensure you prevent the timer event from happening after you dispose the object.

Comment: I probably should have wrote more about what all was going on with the app, but I didn't want my post to be too long. I tried putting the text information in the tag as well but it wasn't retained. Decided to just box it and use that value. Thank you for your help Peter.